# Jquery object replaces value in array

Tags: jquery, json

I'm creating products as a object in jquery and putting them into an array, but the result is two identical. It easy to understand if I just put an example.

```
var product = {
  id: 0,
  name: 'Tomato',
  price: 500
};

var array_products = new Array();

//each loops 2
$.each(data, function(i, item) {
  var new_product = product;
  new_product.id = i;
  new_product.name = "new Tomato " + i;
  new_product.price = 700;

  array_products.push(new_product);
});

console.log(array_products);
```

Result:

```
0: {
  id: 1,
  name: "new Tomato 1",
  price: 700
}
1: {
  id: 1,
  name: "new Tomato 1",
  price: 700
}
```

The problem here is that in the second loop when I "create" the new product, replace the values in the array at the position 0. The result is two equal products instead of two different. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are not creating new objects.  You are simply assigning new_product to point to product.  Also you have to do to fix this, is copy your object definition up top down into your each, so it creates a new object each time.

Comment: Also consider using map, rather than each, for this situation.  `map()` is made for translations like this.

Comment: This might be informative: [Learning how references work in JavaScript](https://medium.com/@naveenkarippai/learning-how-references-work-in-javascript-a066a4e15600)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change the object definition.

```
var product = function Product(){
    this.id = null;
    this.name = null;
    this.price = null;
}
```

And your loop becomes:

```
$.each(data, function(i, item) {
  var new_product = new product();
  new_product.id = i; 
  new_product.name = 'new Tomato '+i;
  new_product.price = 700;
  array_products.push(new_product);
});
```

In case you wanted to clone an existing object and change a few properties, then your loop will be:

```
var new_product = Object.assign({}, existingProductObject); ;
new_product.id = i; 
array_products.push(new_product);
```

[Here is a working sample](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QxzxZR?editors=1111)

Comment: This is great for what I need, thanks... But what if I want to use a base product with info to create a new product just to change one value. 

Ej. p1 = {id: 1, price 500, tomato}, 

p2 = p1; 
p2.id = 2;

Comment: @PedroJoaquín Updated the sample code and also the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can perform simple translation like this with `map()`.  Also in order to make the object different, you have to create a new object each time.  Either by creating it and changing it, or you could just simply create it with the values that you would later assign to it.

```js
var array_products = $.map(data, function(i, item) {
  return {
    id: i,
    name: 'product_'+ i,
    price: 500
  };
});

console.log(array_products);
```